# Trait implementation not found in Rust 1.70

Tags: rust, traits

I was using the [srx](https://docs.rs/srx/0.1.3/srx/) crate and it was working correctly under Rust 1.61. Now, I updated to Rust 1.70 and it cannot find the `FromStr` trait implementation.

An example code that works in 1.61 but not in 1.70:

```rust
use std::fs::read_to_string;
use std::fs;
use std::str::FromStr;
use srx::SRX;

fn main() {
    let srx_file = "../data/language_tool.segment.srx";
    let _srx2: SRX = read_to_string(srx_file).expect("").parse().unwrap();
    let _srx1 = SRX::from_str(&fs::read_to_string(srx_file).unwrap())?;
}
```

and the compiler errors:

```rust
error[E0277]: the trait bound `SRX: FromStr` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:58
  |
8 |     let _srx2: SRX = read_to_string(srx_file).expect("").parse().unwrap();
  |                                                          ^^^^^ the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `SRX`
  |
  = help: the following other types implement trait `FromStr`:
            IpAddr
            Ipv4Addr
            Ipv6Addr
            NonZeroI128
            NonZeroI16
            NonZeroI32
            NonZeroI64
            NonZeroI8
          and 31 others
note: required by a bound in `core::str::<impl str>::parse`
 --> /rustc/90c541806f23a127002de5b4038be731ba1458ca/library/core/src/str/mod.rs:2352:5

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `from_str` found for struct `SRX` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |     let _srx1 = SRX::from_str(&fs::read_to_string("data/segment.srx").unwrap())?;
  |                      ^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `SRX`

warning: unused import: `std::str::FromStr`
 --> src/main.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use std::str::FromStr;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

The trait in the library is implemented [here](https://github.com/bminixhofer/srx/blob/2a9e9c0d5ed2d34e64a3ec748b6cc2efd29657e1/src/from_xml.rs#L74).

I'm pretty new to Rust, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or the library is not implementing it correctly for the new rust version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the trait implementation of `FromStr` for `SRX`, you'll see that it is guarded by a [feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html):

```
#[cfg_attr(docsrs, doc(cfg(feature = "from_xml")))] // only implement FromStr if the from_xml feature is enabled
impl FromStr for SRX {
    type Err = Error;
    fn from_str(string: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        schema::from_str(string)
            .map_err(Error::from)
            .and_then(SRX::try_from)
    }
}
```

This is also indicated in the [docs](https://docs.rs/srx/0.1.3/srx/struct.SRX.html#impl-FromStr) with a violet box stating that:

> This is supported on **crate feature `from_xml`** only.

To fix this, you need to enable the `from_xml` feature for the `srx` crate in your `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
srx = { version = "0.1", features = ["from_xml"] }
```

Comment: Thanks! I though it was because of the Rust version but, indeed, was because in the new project using Rust 1.70, I was using srx as a dependency. In the previous one, I was just using the srx code directly, adding a main.rs. Therefore `cargo build --all-features` was including that feature succesfully. In the new project I was doing the same compilation command, but I guess if I use the crate as a dependency, the feature added in the `Cargo.toml` is needed and `cargo build --all-features` is not enough?

Comment: `--all-features` only enables all features of your crate, not those of your dependencies. You define which features you need from your dependencies in your `Cargo.toml` file. You can hide the features you enable in your dependencies behind features you create in your crate, if you have the need: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#dependency-features.